# How to type a decorator factory correctly?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-typing

I have already posted this example at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15594, but I suspect it may not even be a bug (instead, I may be typing incorrectly) and I hope for help by this larger community.

In the example code below, `mypy` does not seem to properly bind the return type of the decorated function (`int`) to `T`. Instead, I am seeing references to ``` T``-2 ```, which I am not sure I fully know what it is.

(`Pylance` reports `int` for the result of `fun()`, but I am not sure it checks the decorators at all.)

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, reveal_type

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")

def decorator_factory(
    decorator_: Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    return decorator_

@decorator_factory
def decorator(fun_: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
    return fun_

@decorator
def fun() -> int:
    return 0

var = fun()
print(type(var))  # int

reveal_type(decorator_factory)
reveal_type(decorator)
reveal_type(fun)
reveal_type(var)  # expected 'int', got 'T`-2' (Pylance reports 'int')
```

The problem disappears when I remove `@decorator_factory`, so it must be something about typing the decorator factory.

https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15594 also has closely related examples based on `decorator.decorator`-style, caller-based decorators that fail with `T-1`.

Comment: Any exposure of a raw type variable (``T`-2`` is a typevar name with it's internal ID appended - two typevars with same ID resolve to one type in the same context) in a `reveal_type` outside of generic context is a `mypy` bug. Your typing looks correct to me, and there are known problems with `mypy` and inference in higher-order callables (e.g. consider this old issue about typevars scoping in aliases, which is close: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13449)

Comment: For this particular example, both `decorator_factory` and `decorator` can be simplified to `(arg: T) -> T`, in which case `reveal_type(var)` should also report `int` in mypy. Could you provide a more complex example, where the argument and return types are different?

Comment: @dROOOze you are right! `def decorator_factory(decorator_: T) -> T:` fixes the issue already. Unfortunately, I do not see how I can use this to fix examples 2 and 3 in https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15594. Do you want me to copy them over here or are you good looking at the GitHub issue?